# C++ 2 Overloads have similar Conversions- Game Project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Error:

```
Source\_Interface\WndTaskBar.cpp(9681) : error C2666: 'CTexture::RenderRotate' : 2 overloads have similar conversions

    Source\_Common\2DRender.h(245): could be 'void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,BOOL,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)'

    Source\_Common\2DRender.h(240): or       'void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)'
            while trying to match the argument list '(C2DRender *, CPoint, float, int, float, float)'

    Source\Source\_Interface\WndTaskBar.cpp(9682) : error C2666: 'CTexture::RenderRotate' : 2 overloads have similar conversions

    Source\_Common\2DRender.h(245): could be 'void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,BOOL,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)'

    Source\_Common\2DRender.h(240): or       'void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)'
            while trying to match the argument list '(C2DRender *, CPoint, float, int, float, float)'
```

WndTaskBar.cpp

```
9679    if( ( m_nActionSlot > 0 )&&( g_WndMng.m_pWndTaskBar->m_nExecute > 0 ))
9680    {
9681      SlotRt2->RenderRotate( p2DRender, CPoint(0,0), RotateSLOT, 255, 1.0f, 1.0f );
9682      SlotEffect2->RenderRotate( p2DRender, CPoint(0,0), RotateSLOT, m_nFlashAlpha[0], 1.0f, 1.0f );
9683    }
9684    else
9685    {
9686      SlotRt2->Render( p2DRender, CPoint(0,0), 255 );
9687      SlotEffect2->Render( p2DRender, CPoint(0,0), 0);
9688    }
```

2DRender.h ( a few other lines )

```
227 //BOOL LoadTextureFromRes( LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pd3dDevice, LPCTSTR pFileName, D3DCOLOR d3dKeyColor, BOOL bMyLoader = FALSE );
228 void Render( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255 ) {
229     p2DRender->RenderTexture( pt, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa ); 
230 }
231 void Render( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, CPoint pt2, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0 ) {
232     p2DRender->RenderTextureEx( pt, pt2, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa, fscalX, fscalY ); 
233 }
234 void RenderEx2( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, CPoint pt2, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0, D3DCOLOR color = 0 ) {
235     p2DRender->RenderTextureEx2( pt, pt2, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa, fscalX, fscalY, color ); 
236 }
237 void RenderScal( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0 ) {
238     p2DRender->RenderTexture( pt, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa , fscalX, fscalY ); 
239 }
240 void RenderRotate( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, FLOAT fRadian, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0 ) {
241     p2DRender->RenderTextureRotate( pt, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa , fscalX, fscalY, fRadian ); 
242 }
243
244 //added by gmpbigsun : È¸ÀüÃà º¯°æ°¡´É ( center or start point )
245 void RenderRotate( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, FLOAT fRadian, BOOL bCenter, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0 ) {
246     p2DRender->RenderTextureRotate( pt, this, dwBlendFactorAlhpa, fRadian, bCenter, fscalX, fscalY ); 
247 }
248 
249 void Render2( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, D3DCOLOR color, float fscalX = 1.0f, float fscalY = 1.0f ) {
250     p2DRender->RenderTexture2( pt, this, fscalX, fscalY, color ); 
251 }
252 void RenderScal2( C2DRender* p2DRender, CPoint pt, DWORD dwBlendFactorAlhpa = 255, FLOAT fscalX = 1.0, FLOAT fscalY = 1.0, D3DCOLOR color = 0 ) {
253     p2DRender->RenderTextureColor( pt, this, fscalX, fscalY, color ); 
254 }
```

So im really really new to C++ I know some basics and im trying to learn as i go by going trial and error with this Pre-built project, Not the best way to learn, but it'll teach me enough to get by with what i need.

From what i understand the there are two different conversions and the compiler doesn't know which of the two definitions to use, right?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler says when you call the function, the argument list is `(C2DRender *, CPoint, float, int, float, float)`. But there is no exact match for the call.

There are two candidates,

```
void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,BOOL,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)
```

and
    void CTexture::RenderRotate(C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT)

You can say, `int` can be converted to `BOOL` or `DWORD` to match one of the candidates but the compiler considers both are equally good. So it can not decide and ask for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Look at  your code on this line:

```
Source\Source\_Interface\WndTaskBar.cpp(9682) : error C2666: 'CTexture::RenderRotate' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
```

and look carefully at the types of the parameters. The compiler says they evaluate to

```
C2DRender *, CPoint, float, int, float, float
```

You have two very similar function fingerprints, neither of which is an *exact* match but both of them can be made to take the arguments you supplied with some conversion.

Since the argument counts are different, I suspect you have experienced your first lesson in why not to use default arguments.

```
C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,BOOL,DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT
C2DRender *,CPoint,FLOAT,     DWORD,FLOAT,FLOAT
```

The compiler can translate "int" to both BOOL and DWORD, and if the floats in one or both function have default values, it can flesh out the rest.

You can fix it by specifying exactly what you are trying to call:

```
RenderRotate(renderer, point, float1, (BOOL)theBoolValue, (DWORD)theDwordValue, float2, float3);
```